# Sencha 2.4.2 cordova app stuck at "Device Ready" Screen on device

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, senchatouch-2.4

I am new to sencha and creating a app which is coming up on browser but not device.
I have followed basic steps as mentioned in tutorial :
https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/getting_started/building_your_first_app.html

To simulate the case, here are the steps we executed:

- sencha -sdk  generate app MyApp
- sencha cordova init com.mycompany.MyApp MyApp
- sencha web start         (with this we are able to run in browser)
- Updated app.json to include android:

  ```
  "builds": {
    "web": {"default": true},
      "android": {
      "packager": "cordova",
      "cordova" : {                
            "config": {       
              "platforms": "android",
              "id": "com.mycompany.MyApp",
              "name": "MyApp"
          }
      }
  }
  },
  ```
- sencha app build android
- sencha app build -run android
- Post this we were able to open app in android studio from cordova/platforms/android
- when we executed from studio, it is always stuck at "Apache Cordova- Device is ready " screen .. which is from the html of MyApp/cordova/platforms/android/assets/www/index.html and it is not  referring to /MyApp/index.html

Its same behaviour on iOS as well!!

Are we missing out any steps here ?

Comment: Hm I don't like the settings in your app.json, I always used this one http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/cordova_phonegap.html#cordova_phonegap_-_developing_a_cordova_app the last one in that section, so you have builds object with native object and than use `sencha app build native` cos in your example I think that you have specified build 'web' not android. Also please post the version of Sencha Cmd you are using.

Comment: Sencha cmd version is : Sencha Cmd v6.2.0.103
You are right. Its not native . The command I am using is "sencha app build -run android" .
web is added by default, and for android build I have added "android" build.
Its actually as per the steps mentioned in docs.

Answer (score 0):

You app.json was not structured properly. Edit your app.json to reflect below and run `sencha app build`.

```
"builds": {
    "native": {
        "default": true,
        "packager": "cordova",
        "cordova" : {                
            "config": {       
                "platforms": "android",
                "id": "com.mycompany.MyApp",
                "name": "MyApp"
            }
        }
    }
},
```